# Rotating a linked list clockwise in class

Tags: c++, linked-list, rotation

I can rotate lists usually using a function like 
`void rRotate(Node *head);`
However currently i'm implementing it into a Class Node{} which only really changes the way you access the head (using this keyword). Yet no matter which way I type it in a way that makes sense to me, I either get a seg fault, a missing tail, or just the head.
As of now my current code looks like this :

```
Node *Node::rRotate(){
    Node *iterator = this;
    while(iterator->next->next!=NULL) iterator=iterator->next;
      iterator->next->next=this;
      Node *newHead = iterator->next;
      iterator->next=NULL;
      return newHead;
}
```

and My implementation

```
int main() {

  Node *head = new Node(2);
  head->add(3);
  head->add(5);
  head->add(7);
  head->Node::rRotate();
  head->print();
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Currently Outputs:

```
2 3 5
```

I may have a few errors in the function in its current state but I've tried so many different options it seems i'm missing something major.. If you can find the issue, ill get back to you and let you know if it works, Thanks!

Comment: Think about it, `while(iterator->next->next!=NULL)`, what if `iterator->next == NULL`, and you are access next from NULL, you need to handle this situation.

Comment: How could iterator->next = NULL if it stops when ->next->next = NULL?       Edit: Actually I see what you mean, ill fix that

Comment: When the size of linked list is 0 or 1, I see this is not the problem of your code.